# Display output from a pre-defined function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to learn shiny. As an example I would like to create an app that will take one parameter (number of components k) as an input and then display the output of the normalmixEM function from mixtools, given the Old Faithful data set.
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(mixtools)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of components
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("components",
                        "Number of components:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 10,
                        value = 2)
        ),

        # Show a table of the EM parameters
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput(outputId = "ptable")
        )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

    #calculate the parameters
    mixture<-normalmixEM(x=faithful, k= sliderInput)
    output$ptable <- renderTable({
    data.frame(c(mixture$mu, mixture$sigma))
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think my mistake is at the point where I try to extract mu and sigma from the mixture. How can I take the output from the normalmixEM function and display it in the app?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few issues with your current implementation.

First, you need to include your call to `normalmixEM()` inside of your call to `renderTable()`, because it needs to be [reactive](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

```r
output$ptable <- renderTable({
    mixture<-normalmixEM(x=faithful, k= sliderInput)
    data.frame(c(mixture$mu, mixture$sigma))
  })
```

Second, you are passing `faithful` to the `x` argument. `faithful` is a dataframe, but `x` requires a vector, per the documentation `?normalmixEM`:

> x
>
> A vector of length n consisting of the data.

So you would want:

```r
output$ptable <- renderTable({
    mixture<-normalmixEM(x=faithful$waiting, k= sliderInput)
    data.frame(c(mixture$mu, mixture$sigma))
  })
```

Third, in Shiny you access inputs through the built-in reactive list `input`, so the input value from your `components` input would be accessed with `input$components`, i.e.

```r
output$ptable <- renderTable({
    mixture<-normalmixEM(x=faithful$waiting, k= inputs$component)
    data.frame(c(mixture$mu, mixture$sigma))
  })
```

Finally, you are using `renderTable()` with `dataTableOutput()`. `renderTable()` requires `tableOutput()` on the output side, whereas `dataTableOutput()` requires `renderDataTable()` on the server side - you are mixing 2 different types of tables. Using `tableOutput()` should solve the problem.

```r
library(shiny)
library(mixtools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of components
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("components",
                "Number of components:",
                min = 1,
                max = 10,
                value = 2)
  ),
  
  # Show a table of the EM parameters
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput(outputId = "ptable")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #calculate the parameters
  output$ptable <- renderTable({
    mixture<-normalmixEM(faithful$waiting, k= input$components)
    data.frame(c(mixture$mu, mixture$sigma))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Very good explanation! However, I would separate the code a bit and don't call `normalmixEM` directly in `renderTable` but make an extra `reactive`